# How to improve a GetComponent<> method

Tags: c++, components

I've been debugging a method in another question and even though it has been fixed comments have led to me to believe that I'm doing something badly, but no one has been able to suggest how to improve it.

My rendering engine I'm writing uses a component system inspired by unity. The `GetComponent<>()` method returns a component of the given type from an object if present, and returns `nullptr` if the given component is not present. All components inherit from a common `Component` base class.

Here is the code:

```
template <typename CompType>
inline CompType getComponent()
{
    for(Component * currComp : compStruct.components)
    {
        CompType currentEntry = dynamic_cast<CompType>(currComp);
        if (currentEntry != nullptr)
        {
            return currentEntry;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Usage as follows:

```
//Returns a valid RenderConditions pointer if the object has that component
RenderConditions* rc = go->getComponent<RenderConditions*>();
```

The `dynamic_cast` is obviously undesirable, especially as this system could be used multiple times a frame for RenderComponents, AnimationComponents, Transform or anything. I've had a couple of ideas around having a fixed "ID" for every type of component but the crux of it is I want the user of this game engine to be able to write their own components for the system, and without a dynamic_cast I've found it'll only work with the component #included in object.h

Any ideas how to improve?

Comment: Instead of having one container for all components, simply have a separate container for each component type, and this becomes a no-brainer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how would this work when there are potentially 100+ component types and they aren't all known at compile time? The engine compiles to a .lib which is then used by another c++ to create a game

Comment: This would work by assigning a unique id to each component type, and putting all of them into a map or multimap, and then simply accessing the correct key.

Comment: How could I automate this process? I know in unity when I make a monobehaviour I don't have to come up with a unique ID myself. Also how could I then implement a method where I can pass in the component type as an argument?

Comment: @JVApen is there a way to move it there? Seems counter-productive to close the question when there is active conversation

Comment: @WillHain I can't, wasn't even able to select it from the predefined list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### **Potential pitfall**:

Do not use this method to store persistent (e.g on disk) type metadata, because typeid might change between different invocations of the same program.

---

As a side note: in Unity the `GetComponent` method is indeed expensive, so it is not recommended to call it frequently (i.e. several times per frame). Instead, you should get it and cache the result somewhere else.

---

So to implement this you can use the `typeid` operator and `std::type_index` provided by the standard. `std::type_index` is unique for every type and can be used as a map key (see [this reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index)).

Here is an example implementation:

```cpp
#include <typeindex>
#include <map>
#include <cassert>

//Base class of all components
class Component {
public:
    virtual ~Component() = default;
    Component(const Component& rhs) = delete;
protected:
    Component() = default;
};

class Rigidbody : public Component {

};

class MeshRenderer : public Component {

};

class Text : public Component {
public:
    std::string text;
};

class GameObject {
private:
    std::multimap<std::type_index, Component*> m_components;
public:
    template<typename T, 
        typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Component, T>>>
    T* add_component() {
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(m_components.insert(std::make_pair(std::type_index(typeid(T)), new T))->second);
    }

    template<typename T, 
        typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Component, T>>>
    T* get_component() {
        auto it = m_components.find(std::type_index(typeid(T)));
        if (it == m_components.end()) return nullptr;
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(it->second);
    }
};

int main() {
    GameObject gm;
    gm.add_component<MeshRenderer>();
    auto& text = *gm.add_component<Text>();
    assert(gm.get_component<MeshRenderer>() != nullptr);
    assert(gm.get_component<Rigidbody>() == nullptr);
    text.text = "Hello, World!";
    std::cout << gm.get_component<Text>()->text << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be: `Hello, World!`